# I need help moding Minecraft

Tags: minecraft

Well, first please don’t hold this question again? My problem is I'm trying to mod Minecraft I'm using a Ubuntu 14.04 and I don’t know what to do, please give me some instructions on what to do. Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid if you want a "how to mod minecraft" guide then this site isn't for you. That's not only off-topic but much too broad. Do you have a question about modding minecraft that is specific to Ubuntu? If so then please post *that*. Or you could find a forum (or even a Q/A site like us!) dedicated to minecraft mods :)

Comment: I’m on a site where you ask questions about Ubuntu things, im using Ubuntu to play mc I didn’t think I had to explain that but ok?

Comment: Hmm, I just realized something. Are you trying to *add* mods to Minecraft or *write* mods? The former is on-topic (although it would help to know what mods specifically), the latter not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not Ubuntu specific question.
You can read mod Minecraft on the page where you downloaded that mod. Usually you just open `minecraft.jar` as zip archive and put downloaded `.class` files there.

---

I recommend that you try out [MagicLauncher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-100-mods-options-news/).  This allows you to install and enable/disable Minecraft mods really easily.

Once you run it click on Setup. You will be presented with this dialog:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOWb0.png]

Then to add a mod click Add and select the zip of the mod you want to install. Really simple!

Comment: how would i run it?

Comment: `Double click the downloaded file and the MagicLauncher should start.`

Comment: it says                                                                                                                                                     The file '/home/tanya/inserted into mc/MagicLauncher_1.3.0.jar' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit.

Comment: As it says: "read about the executable bit" ;) and then just set it
or you can use terminal command `java -jar MagicLauncher_1.3.0.jar`